How to send PDF file using Baileys API that integrated to Laravel
I want to send invoices to WhatsApp number, I tried using a text field in body it just send a link the PDF, how can I actually attach it?
I'm using Guzzle to communicate with the local Baileys API.
I'm using the updated version BaileysAPI-Laravel from here.
$invoiceName = str_replace(' ', '%20', $generatedInvoice->getFile()->getFilename());
        $url = asset('pdf/'. $invoiceName);
        $updateOrder = Order::find($orderId);
        if($generatedInvoice->getStatusCode() == 200){
            //* Create method to send the pdf to whatsapp
            $response = $client->request('GET','http://localhost:3000/sessions/',['headers'=> [
                'x-api-key'  => 'testAPI',
            ]]);
            $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            $data = json_decode($body,true);
            $status = $data[0]['status'];
            if($status == "AUTHENTICATED"){
                $response = $client->request('POST','http://localhost:3000/'.$SesId.'/messages/send',[
                    'headers' => ['x-api-key' => 'testAPI'],
                    'json'=> [
                        'jid' => '62xxxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net',
                        'type' => 'number',
                        'message' => ["text"  => 'Your invoice is ready, please download it here: '.$url,
                        ]
                    ]
                ]);
                dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
            }

The output is hyperlink like this,

How do I make the API attach the usual pdf file ?
I've read the documentation in here they giving a examples like sending audio, image, gif etc. but not PDF.
Is there any specific parameter that can turn link to a attached file or something?
